# Php post function with header()

Tags: php, post

I'm new to PHP. I want to send data from one page to another page by post.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{

header("location:nextpage.php");
//here i want to send data coming from my text box's by post function
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4939261/362536  Also, use full URLs with your `Location:` headers.

Comment: Your prerequisite won't work. Redirects will always use GET. You either need a `<form>` with `method=POST`, or a server-side request (= no redirect in the browser) using a HTTP lib.

Comment: @mario, That is not entirely true.  It isn't specified what the browser should do when directing with POST data.  But yes, the behavior cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: if i use form with post method then how do i check for validations like require field validations

Answer (score 2):

You should just target the right page to begin with.

```
<form action="your-processing-script.php" method="post">
```

Keep in mind the action is relative, so depending on your file structure, you may want a slash before the file url to prevent confusion.

```
/your-processing-script.php
```

Comment: +1 for keeping it simple. curl or header("Location: ...") is no match for the good old refer-to-the-right-page-directly-trick

Comment: thank you but i have to check some validations before posting the data
like required field validate

Comment: if i use this in directly in form then i will not be able to check some validations before posting the data
like required field validate

Comment: You can do validation on your target and pass back to the form page with header. You can set posted values in session to re-populate the form, etc. there are many ways to go about doing this

Comment: yes i know the other ways but here i just want to know "is that possible to use post function with header() "

Comment: not while maintaining the values of $_POST unless you use a medium to transfer and re-populate, which is not advised. header is a redirect page load knowing nothing except the parameter you pass it. You would need to store the values of post in a temp table, session, or other means to relay the info. But in that you can expose risk depending on the values you try to pass openly. I think the real question is what is your file structure that calls for an action like this. Normally you validate, then call a method to process or reload the form on error.